# Find three nonzero vectors $x, y, b$ than $Ax = b, By = b$.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Find three nonzero vectors $x, y, b \in R^3$ than $Ax = b, By = b$, where

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2\\ 
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

My answer:
Using that $Ax=b$ & $By=b$, 
$$x=By$$
$$A(By)=b$$
$$(AB)y=b$$
Now solving the new system of equations:
$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2\\ 
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & 1\\ 
2 & 0 & 1\\ 
2 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which implies that $\det AB=0$. What it implies does not exist and such that it solves the system. And therefore that does not exist three nonzero vectors $x, y, b \in R^3$ than $Ax = b, By = b$.

I am not sure that my answer is correct, it will help me a lot to know if I do it well.

Comment: how did you get to $x=By$?

Comment: Can you think of a condition that guarantees that $Ax=b$ has a solution at all? What does this say about $b$ if both $Ax=b$ and $By=b$ have solutions?

Comment: The observation by @LinAlg aside, how does $\det(AB)=0$ imply that $ABy=b$ has no solution?